# Generate flexdashboard in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, flexdashboard

**In Rmarkdown to generate a flexdashboard**, I want to import an excel sheet and use selectInput statement to select any of 2,3,4,5 columns (product1,product2,product3,product4) from excel sheet and plot a scatter chart for column1(Day) vs selected column from selectInput statement(product1 or product2 or product3 or product4). Can someone please help me with the R code?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0IwL.png)

> > --- title: "General plots" 
> >            author: "Aravind" date: "April 1st,2018" output: 
> >          flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
> >          orientation:  columns
> >
> > ### runtime: shiny
> >
> > `{r, echo=FALSE} 
> >     library(readxl) 
> >     library(flexdashboard)
> >     library(shiny)
> >     library(plotly) 
> >     data_to_plot<-read_excel("random.xlsx")`
> >      
> >     Inputs {.sidebar}
> >     `{r Global Filter Panel, echo=FALSE} 
> >     selectInput("Product","Activity",choices=c('product1','product2','product3','product4'),selected=NULL,width = '400px')`
> >      
> >     Under this tab chart will be displayed
> >
> > ### Chart {.tabsets .tabset-fade}
> >
> > #### Chart ```{r echo=FALSE, message=FALSE}
> >
> > renderPlotly(
> >     p<-plot_ly(
> >     data_to_plot,x=~Product,y=~Day,
> >     color ="red",
> >     type="scatter")%>% 
> >     layout(title="Scatter plot using R plotly",
> >     xaxis=list(title="Day"),yaxis=list(title="Product"),
> >     legend=list(x=1,y=0.5))%>%
> >     p )
> >
> > ```

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far. Where is your code attempt? Where did you get stuck? There are plenty of tutorials/resources available that would get you started. SO is not a free code writing service. You need to demonstrate some effort! Also please review [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions here on SO.

Comment: Hi Maurits, I'm new to SO and thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: I have included the code that i have tried so far in the description. Please do let me know where i'm making the mistake or how should i approach it.

Answer (score 1):

Little bit of messy formatting in your question that you might want to fix but the answer isn't too hard.

You used

```
   selectInput("Product","Activity",choices=c('product1','product2','product3','product4'),selected=NULL,width = '400px')
```

So, a input selection with inputID=`Product`. In shiny / flexdashboard this will create a variable `input$Product`.

Then you use `plot_ly()` with

```
plot_ly( data_to_plot,x=~Product,y=~Day....
```

Here you use the `Product` variable, which isn't assigned anywhere unless it's a column in your dataframe. Instead try this,

```
plot_ly( data_to_plot,x=~input$Product,y=~Day....
```

Hence, use `input$Product` to get the value from your Shiny `selectInput()`.
Hope that will get you going. I'm sure this will look familiar to you if you've gone through some tutorials on flexdashboards.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Lodewic Van Twillert, it worked. Can you please suggest a solution for this as well [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49859564/deploy-rmarkdown-web-app-on-server). Eagerly waiting for your answer...thanks in advance