# Deploy Rmarkdown web app on server

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I have developed a web application(flexdashboard) in runtime shiny by importing excel data into rmarkdown. I want to deploy it on a server which should work in real time i.e;i will share the link with users so that the end users can see what is happening in real time and the changes that are made to the data in excel data would also be reflected in the web app i.e; dashboard. Please let me know on how to deploy this Rmarkdown web app on Linux server (or any cost efficient server)?
Also please let me know if we can develop some dynamic web pages in rmarkdown.
Any kind of help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is currently a bit too broad for Stackoverflow: the site is about creating specific solutions to coding issues. However check out Shinyapps for basic hosting: http://www.shinyapps.io/

Comment: I have done the coding part but i'm facing issue with this one. Without deploying app, the code that I have implemented is not useful. I have checked the website that you have shared, the cost for hosting is high as number of participants keeps on increasing. Can we host it on linux or ubuntu server. If yes, please let me know. Thanks

Comment: Check out this if you want a self-hosted version: https://www.rstudio.com/products/shiny/download-server/ . Shiny apps are generally more expensive to host as they require server-side processing.